# How to solve SonarScanner execution java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarscanner

I am using pipeline this pipeline
[image]

Project size approx(500MB).

I am getting errors during scanning code:

ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space...more

[image]

[image]

Also, I have set the below config and Also I have tried with more RAM -Xmx2G and more...
(sonar.exclusions=**/*.doc, **/*.cls , **/*.docx, **/*.ipch, resources/* , vendors/**/* , **/vendors/**/* , public/admin/images/** , public/admin/vendor/**/* , public/admin/var/**/* , public/**/* , public/assets/**/* , public/images/** , public/sales_assets/images/**)

sonar.web.javaOpts=-Xmx1024m -Xms256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

sonar.ce.javaOpts=-Xmx1024m -Xms512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xmx512m -Xms512m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

but the same issue.

Also, I have followed many StackOverflow link settings and applied them but still getting the same issue.